# Add/remove validation rules Dynamically using add/removeClass({required:true,max:.........})

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

in jquery.validate

my requirement:

the input-text will be  validated only if the checkbox in the same row  is be checked!

```
$("[name='ck']").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).parent().parent().find("[name='t']");
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
            text.addClass("required");
        } else {
            text.removeClass("required");
        }
    });
```

the code is OK! but when i change the rule to *`{required:true,number:true,max:5}`* ,it is not work!

only the input-text of the   first checkbox be checked will be validated!
when the second checkbox be clicked,the relevant input-text will not be validated.

so

```
addClass("{required:true,number:true,max:5}");
```

Is the way to Add/remove validation rules Dynamically is NOT legal,
but why  it will be work only once!

Comment: `addClass()` is for adding CSS classes.  It doesn't work for you because the string `{required:true,number:true,max:5}` is not a CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the `depends` callback to dynamically choose whether or not the rule should be required.

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#contactform_email:checked")
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This example was pulled from the [jquery validation page](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/)